# iOS 11 iPad multitasking aka 'Side by Side' with Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad, ios11, split-screen

I'm creating an app using Cordova and I would love for my app on the iPad to use this cool feature called "Split View" aka "Apps Side by Side" or "multitasking" (see picture "My goal")

- If I'm using a build target iOS 9 my app simply works as it was from the days of iOS #1
- If I'm using a build target iOS 11 my app can be overlapped by another app, but that's it (see picture "My best result so far")

I'm using built-in apps to illustrate my idea:

### My goal:

[image]

### My best result so far (with build target iOS 11):

[image]

So I'm lost:

1. Do I really need to drop support for iOS 9.x to do that?
2. Any suggestions on how actually implement this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This should work out of the box for any iOS 11 application.

Two reasons why it would not work:

1. Your app has "Requires full screen" enabled under General -> Deployment info, this prevents split screen
2. You miss that you should grab the "small grey bar" at the top of the "Slide Over" application and drag it to the right to get split screen, test to run Safari and Notes as split screen so you are sure that you do the interaction correctly